# @Html.CheckBox("IsMACUnique",new { @checked = "checked" } )

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following inside my asp.net mvc view:-

```
 @Html.CheckBox("IsMACUnique",new  { @checked = "checked" } )
```

But if the user check the checkbox the value will be posted back as "true,false".I was expecting  that in case the user check the checkbook then the value will be true, else the value will be false. can anyone advice on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Html.Checkbox("Visible") returns "true, false" in ASP.NET MVC 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936048/why-html-checkboxvisible-returns-true-false-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

Comment: i tried the folloiwng  <input type="CheckBox" name="IsIPUnique" value="true" @Html.Raw(Model.IsIPUnique ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")/> IP Unique.  but it will not check the checkbox incase the Model.IsIPUnique = true ?!!

Comment: How are you accessing the POST'ed result? If you let MVC's default model binder do its work, it will respond correctly to the posted value and turn "true,false" back into a bool with value `true` and a "false" into `false`. Also, your example in the comment works fine for me in terms of outputting an `<input type="checkbox" ... />` that's checked if `Model.IsIPUnique` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct. You can check followings:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsMACUnique, new  { @checked = "checked" } )
```

May be any jquery code prevents to it. Look for any `check` or `checked` classes in your .css files. If there is, use

```
@Html.CheckBox("IsMACUnique", new { @class = "check" })
```