# Logical comparison in MVC Controller using the string "false,true" after a form is submitted. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, boolean-logic

I'm modifying a C# MVC web application implemented by some other developer and sometimes I find the following logical comparison:

`client.AttributeName = Request["AttributeName"] == "false,true";`

Is this a correct expression? If so, what's this supposed to do?

Comment: How are we supposed to know if it's correct?  We don't know what it's *supposed* to do.  If you want to know what it does, you could start by running it a few times and looking at what's going on in the debugger, or by looking up what the various operators do in the language documentation.

Comment: Sir, the part in question here is the `"false,true"` string expression; don't know if it is a valid logical expression or just a plain "string". I'm perfectly aware that what you described is an option but I want to learn the "theory" or best practices for C# regarding that. There's no need for sarcasm.

Comment: I was not being sarcastic at all.  I was indicating that we have no idea what you think this does, or what it should do, and thus have no possible way of indicating it's correctness.  if you want us to be able to tell you if it's correct, you need to indicate what the requirements are for this method.  There is nothing sarcastic about that; it is a request for information.  As for the rest, if you want to learn more then taking the time to figure out how things work yourself is *exactly* how you go about learning such things.  Just asking people to tell you makes it *harder* for you to learn.

Comment: @Servy I've seen developers confused by this before - it's the counter-intuitive way ASP.Net works around checkbox inputs only posting back if they're true. As such I think it's a worthwhile question that shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @Keith Who said anything about deleting the question?  Also, there's a *huge* difference between asking *what* something is doing, and *why* it's doing that.  Determining *what* it's doing is quite easy, and the author is most certainly capable of determining that out on his own.  Knowing *why* someone wrote code that does that is a radically different question.

Comment: @Servy yeah, he's asking the wrong question, but it is confusing. There were two votes to close and I assumed that you were one of them, my apologies.

Comment: @Keith I most certainly did vote to close.  Closing and deleting are *entirely* different things.

Comment: Thanks @Keith! Thank you very much for taking your time, for being elegant, polite and not making judgmental comments out of the gate. My question came up after noticing the expression a couple of times in the code and being unable to truly understand the behavior, reasoning or purpose behind it even after googling the topic.Thanks! We need more developers like you.

Comment: @Servy I am not a native English speaker and maybe my writing skills were not the most clear but Keith at least made an effort on figuring out what I meant and offered a helping hand. That's what matters!

Comment: @DevJE Keith took a wild guess at what he thought that you meant given incomplete information.  Rather than guessing, I choose to tell you what information your question was lacking so that it could be edited into a well written, quality, *answerable* question.  As it is, Keith's answer doesn't answer the question that you asked.  It asks the question that you might, possibly, maybe, intended to ask, but it doesn't answer what you *did* ask.  The site has dedicated itself to being a repository of quality questions and answers.  Encouraging users to improve their questions serves that purpose.

Comment: @Servy Your approach was unnecessary; since I understood your point I've already modified the question in an effort to make it more clear.

Comment: @DevJE How is it unnecessary to indicate that the question does not contain enough information to be answerable?  That seems entirely necessary in my mind.  Refusing to provide the information requested to make the question answerable (which, for the record, you still have not provided) is very problematic behavior.  In this case you got lucky and someone guessed right.  Eventually that won't happen, and you'll need to answer the clarifying questions if you want to get an answer.

Comment: @Servy As I just said, I already tried fixing the question. What was totally unnecessary is your first reply. Be kind and explain yourself, that will get your farther.

Comment: @DevJE It seems that you're reading malice into a genuine request for information, combined with helpful tips to both help you solve your problem as well as improve your question.  There is no malice or rudeness there, merely terseness.  I don't even see how you can interpret those comments as inappropriate when *trying* to view them from that point of view.

Comment: @Servy actually I didn't take a _wild guess_. I've been a manager of developers for years and I've seen a someone new to MVC checkboxes confused by exactly this issue before. I had a very good idea of what what causing the confusion, even though the question was asking about string comparisons instead. Beginners to a topic often don't know what to ask, and ask the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC you shouldn't really need to get values from the `Request` object - you should get them in the model or parameters passed into the action.

If you have two HTML inputs with the same name you get their values separated by commas in the result.

I'm guessing that you have an ASP.Net generated checkbox, as this actually outputs something like this:

```
<%:Html.Checkbox("AttributeName")%>
```

Becomes:

```
<input name="AttributeName" type="hidden" value="false" />
<input checked="checked" id="AttributeName" name="AttributeName" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

The second input is there because if an HTML checkbox input is false it sends nothing back in the POST data. This HTML means that the returned value will be either:

- `"false,true"` if the checkbox is checked
- `"false"` if the checkbox is **not** checked

ASP.Net's handlers know how to cope with this, but your predecessor did not.

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936048/why-html-checkboxvisible-returns-true-false-in-asp-net-mvc-2) on why .Net does this.

To fix it you can rely on MVC's built in handling:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(bool AttributeName) 
{
    client.AttributeName = AttributeName; 
}
```

MVC already knows to only accept the last POST back value in the comma separated list, so if you POST `"false,true"` to the method above `AttributeName` will be true.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if that's correct because you didn't say what it suppose to do.

But I can tell you what it does:

```
client.AttributeName = Request["AttributeName"] == "false,true";
```

From right to left: *check if `Request["AttributeName"]` has the same value as `"false,true"` and assign the check result (`true` or `false` as `bool` value) to `client.AttributeName`*.

Comment: So, on C# I can declare a "true,false" string and use it on a logical comparison to check if some object contains either of those two values...and not "null" for example?

Comment: No, it checks if `Request["AttributeName"]` is **exactly** `"false,true"`. IT's not like *one of them* check.

Comment: @DevJE No, that's not what it's doing at all.  It is not doing a contains check, it is not looking for either of two values.  it's seeing if the value is exactly equal to a given string.

Comment: Exactly, that's what bothers me, that's what I thought but since I'm a Java developer getting used to C# I thought that was something that C# "allowed to be done". The correct way then for making sure `Request` contains either `true` or `false` then is the plain old `!=null` or something like that?

Comment: Not sure how you'd use `!= null`, @DevJE, but the typical way would be something like `Request["AttributeName"] == "false" || Request["AttributeName"] == "true"`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is setting client.AttributeName (Boolean) to true or false depending on whether the value in Request["AttributeName"] is equal to the string "false,true"

Not sure what it is supposed do do though - you haven't posted very much information.