# How to get checkbox value properly in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If `formCollection[]` is used, then the `string` returned for the `checkbox` as the result is: `"true,false"`. How do you parse this? Is `Replace()` the only option?

Or should i put all parameters in my `"action method"` (in controller)? Like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string checkbox)
```

What's the proper way?

**UPDATE: for anyone who might run into this (thanks again @meda)**

If you have a strongly typed view, something like this:

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.Car
```

then you can access the whole model in your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Car model)
```

or if you don't have that many "inputs" in your form, then you can use the names of your html inputs in your controller action method as parameters and the parameters will be parsed into the data type you want automatically:

```
public ActionResult Edit(bool checkbox)
```

Comment: This link might help you:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936048/why-html-checkboxvisible-returns-true-false-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Comment: @ImranBalouch i searched stackoverflow, found some ok topics, but haven't found the one you provided. Also i didn't knew that the action method parameter can be a bool like this: `public ActionResult Edit(bool checkbox)`. I used a string and then parsed it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is to not use `formCollection` and to pass a model object to your controller action.

The model property would not be a string but a `boolean` since it could only be checked or unchecked.

For example:

```
public bool MyCheckBox1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm following you here. Could you provide an example for `"pass a model object to your controller action"`?

Comment: I just meant not to use `formCollection[]` but your model, and for the value posted it would be a bool not a string thats all

Comment: You meant something like this `public ActionResult Edit(bool checkbox)`?

Comment: yeah and if you can use models, you want your views to be strongly typed instead of parsing formcollection

Comment: Is it somehow possible to have only 1 parameter? An object with all the data from the form in it? So that i don't have to put all parameters in there?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am saying, you would pass the instance object of your model, but that depends on the situation for an edit action it could be you just need the id  so its fine to have 1 parameter

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639709/Getting-Data-From-View-to-Controller-in-MVC

Comment: This solved my problem. I learned this already in school, but it was a while and i forgot. My views are strongly typed, i just didn't use it. Added this: `public ActionResult CalculateSimpleInterestResult(SimpleInterestModel model)` and everything works perfect. Thanks for the reminder. :)